# tomcat server.xml sybase property

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, sybase

In the `server.xml` for Tomcat I have a `<Resource>` tag with a Sybase datasource working correctly. I need to add the Sybase specific property below to the `<Resource>`:

```
GET_BY_NAME_USES_COLUMN_LABEL = true
```

But I am not sure where to put it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do Sybase, so I can't tell it from top of head, but on all other databases those kind of connection properties are usually to be passed in a query string format of the JDBC connection URL. The [Sybase JDBC documentation](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1009812) confirms that this is true for Sybase as well. Here's an extract of relevance:

> To set a connection property in the URL, append the property name and its value to the URL definition. Use this syntax:
>
> ```
> jdbc:sybase:Tds:host:port/database?property_name=value
> ```
>
> To set multiple connection properties, append each additional connection property and value, preceded by "&." For example:
>
> ```
> jdbc:sybase:Tds:myserver:1234/mydatabase?LITERAL_PARAMS=true&PACKETSIZE=512&HOSTNAME=myhost
> ```

So, this should do it for you:

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:1234?GET_BY_NAME_USES_COLUMN_LABEL=true
```